# Movement doesn't work after applying functions to draw shape?

Tags: function, processing

I'm trying to create a simple space game using Processing.
I've drawn a spaceship and added movements to it using A, D, W, S keys. Here's the code:

```
float shipX=0;
float shipY=0; 


void setup(){
  size(500,500);

}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  stroke(0); //spaceship
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  circle(shipX,shipY,50);
  fill(0);
  circle(shipX,shipY,20);
  triangle(shipX,shipY,shipX-8,shipY+25,shipX+8,shipY+25);
  fill(105,105,105);
  rect(shipX-20,shipY+20,40,5);
  rect(shipX-25,shipY+25,50,15);
  fill(255,255,0);
  triangle(shipX-25,shipY+25,shipX-40,shipY+35,shipX-25,shipY+40);
  triangle(shipX+25,shipY+25,shipX+40,shipY+35,shipX+25,shipY+40);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  arc(shipX,shipY+40,50,20,0,PI, CHORD);  
  
}
  void keyPressed(){ //spaceship movement
    if(key == 's')
    shipY = shipY+10;
    if(key=='w')
    shipY = shipY-10;
    if(key =='a')
    shipX= shipX-5;
    if(key =='d')
    shipX= shipX+5;
  }
```

Later on, I want to call `void drawPlayer(float x, float y)` to draw the ship instead.

However, after drawing the player by calling `drawPlayer(0,0);` in `void draw()`, the movements don't work anymore. Here's the new block of code:

```
float x=0;
float y=0;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
 
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  drawPlayer(50,50);
  }

  void drawPlayer(float x, float y){
  stroke(0); //spaceship
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  circle(x,y,50);
  fill(0);
  circle(x,y,20);
  triangle(x,y,x-8,y+25,x+8,y+25);
  fill(105,105,105);
  rect(x-20,y+20,40,5);
  rect(x-25,y+25,50,15);
  fill(255,255,0);
  triangle(x-25,y+25,x-40,y+35,x-25,y+40);
  triangle(x+25,y+25,x+40,y+35,x+25,y+40);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  arc(x,y+40,50,20,0,PI,CHORD);

  }

  void keyPressed(){ //spaceship movement
    if(key == 's')
    y = y + 10;
    if(key =='w')
    y = y - 10;
    if(key =='a')
    x= x - 5;
    if(key =='d')
    x= x + 5;
  }
```

I'm new to programming, so things get confusing. Is it because the global variable x, y is not called? I've tried putting movements function into `void drawPlayer(float x, float y)` but the ship still can't move. It would be great if anyone can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This line:
`drawPlayer(50,50);`
is sending `50`,`50` as the values for `x` and `y` in your `drawPlayer` function. So no matter what the global x and y values are changed to via keypress, the values inside your function are always 50,50, so the ship never moves.

Simply change it to
`drawPlayer(x,y);`
to send the global values into the function and it should work.

To avoid confusion, you might want to change the names of the global variables so they are different from the local variables that get used inside the function:

```
float shipX=0;
float shipY=0;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
 
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  drawPlayer(shipX, shipY);
}

void drawPlayer(float x, float y){
  stroke(0); //spaceship
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  circle(x,y,50);
  fill(0);
  circle(x,y,20);
  triangle(x,y,x-8,y+25,x+8,y+25);
  fill(105,105,105);
  rect(x-20,y+20,40,5);
  rect(x-25,y+25,50,15);
  fill(255,255,0);
  triangle(x-25,y+25,x-40,y+35,x-25,y+40);
  triangle(x+25,y+25,x+40,y+35,x+25,y+40);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  arc(x,y+40,50,20,0,PI,CHORD);
}

void keyPressed(){ //spaceship movement
  if(key == 's')
  shipY = shipY + 10;
  if(key =='w')
  shipY = shipY - 10;
  if(key =='a')
  shipX = shipX - 5;
  if(key =='d')
  shipX = shipX + 5;
}
```